# Unittest mock pandas to_csv

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv, python-unittest

**mymodule.py**

```
def write_df_to_csv(self, df, modified_fn):
    new_csv = self.path + "/" + modified_fn
    df.to_csv(new_csv, sep=";", encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

**test_mymodule.py**

```
class TestMyModule(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        args = parse_args(["-f", "test1"])
        self.mm = MyModule(args)
        self.mm.path = "Random/path"

    self.test_df = pd.DataFrame(
                [
                    ["bob", "a"],
                    ["sue", "b"],
                    ["sue", "c"],
                    ["joe", "c"],
                    ["bill", "d"],
                    ["max", "b"],
                ],
                columns=["A", "B"],
            )

def test_write_df_to_csv(self):
    to_csv_mock = mock.MagicMock()
    with mock.patch("project.mymodule.to_csv", to_csv_mock, create=True):
        self.mm.write_df_to_csv(self.test_df, "Stuff.csv")
    to_csv_mock.assert_called_with(self.mm.path + "/" + "Stuff.csv")
```

When I run this test, I get:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Random/path/Stuff.csv'
```

I'm trying to mock the `to_csv` in my method. My other tests run as expected, however I'm not sure where I am going wrong with this test. Is my use of MagicMock correct, or am I overlooking something else?

Comment: `project.mymodule.to_csv` isn't the same as the `to_csv` method of Pandas's `DataFrame`, is it?

Comment: @Thomas, I believe it's to do with the df part of df.to_csv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide a minimal, reproducible example, so I had to strip some things out to make this work. I suppose you can fill in the missing bits on your own.

One problem was with `mock.patch("project.mymodule.to_csv", ...)` which tries to mock a *class* named `to_csv` in the *module* at the import path `project.mymodule`. This only "worked" because you passed `create=True`, but of course mocking something that didn't exist before has no effect because nobody will call it.

You *could* mock out the entire `DataFrame` class using `mock.patch("pandas.DataFrame", ...)`. Note: it's not `pd` regardless of how (or even whether) you imported `pandas` in the current module.

But then your unit test will be asserting that `to_csv` was called on *any* `DataFrame`, not necessarily the one you passed in. By mocking *just* the `to_csv` method on the one `DataFrame` object that we are passing into `write_df_to_csv`, the test becomes a bit more comprehensive and also easier to understand. We can do this using `mock.patch.object`.

`mock.patch.object` returns the mock function, on which we can subsequently call assertions. Because it's a method mock, not a free function, we don't need to pass the `self` argument in the assertion.

**project/mymodule.py**

```py
def write_df_to_csv(df, file_name):
    df.to_csv(file_name, sep=";", encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

**project/test_mymodule.py**

```py
import unittest.mock as mock
import unittest

import pandas as pd

import project.mymodule as mm

class TestMyModule(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_write_df_to_csv(self):
        test_df = pd.DataFrame(...)
        with mock.patch.object(test_df, "to_csv") as to_csv_mock:
            mm.write_df_to_csv(test_df, "Stuff.csv")
            to_csv_mock.assert_called_with("Stuff.csv")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**Output**

The test fails in a proper way now, because the arguments don't actually match!

```
$ python -m project.test_mymodule
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_write_df_to_csv (__main__.TestMyModule)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/project/test_mymodule.py", line 25, in test_write_df_to_csv
    to_csv_mock.assert_called_with("Stuff.csv")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/mock.py", line 913, in assert_called_with
    raise AssertionError(_error_message()) from cause
AssertionError: expected call not found.
Expected: to_csv('Stuff.csv')
Actual: to_csv('Stuff.csv', sep=';', encoding='utf-8', index=False)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.003s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Comment: thank you for that. Actually I amended the last line:             to_csv_mock.assert_called_with(self.mm.path + "/" + "Stuff.csv", sep=";", encoding='utf-8', index=False)

Answer (score 5):

Another way would be to

```
import unittest.mock as mock
import unittest
import pandas as pd

import project.mymodule as mm

class TestMyModule(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_write_df_to_csv(self):
        test_df = pd.DataFrame(...)
        with mock.patch("pandas.DataFrame.to_csv") as to_csv_mock:
            mm.write_df_to_csv(test_df, "Stuff.csv")
            to_csv_mock.assert_called_with("Stuff.csv")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()'''
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29893563)

Comment: @rv.kvetch Sorry but this is an exact answer to the question. However, I don't know whether it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the path with a with a forward slash. Here is the corrected code:

```
self.mm.path = "/Random/path/"
```

Also change:

```
to_csv_mock.assert_called_with(self.mm.path + "Stuff.csv")
```

**Edit**: As @Thomas said, I'm not sure if `project.mymodule.to_csv` is correct!

Comment: I changed it, still the same error message

Comment: Oh ok, I'll have to check how mac paths are formatted